# Monitor directory and change ownership of files upon creation

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop, chown, inotifywait

I have tried this method but it does not work...

```
inotifywait -mr -e create /opt/freeswitch/storage/ 2>&-| sed 's/ CREATE //g' |
    while read file; do
    chown apache.apache $file
    done
```

From command line

```
inotifywait -mr -e create /opt/freeswitch/storage/ 2>&-| sed 's/ CREATE //g'
```

gives the exact output that I need with the full path of the file, but the moment I try to output sed to a file or pipe it's output into something else it stops working.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sed` buffers its output when it's writing to a pipe. Use the `-u` option to unbuffer it.

```
inotifywait -mr -e create /opt/freeswitch/storage/ 2>&-| sed -u 's/ CREATE //g' |
    while read file; do
    chown apache.apache $file
    done
```